# System.BadImageFormatException while self-hosting service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dll, wcf-binding

I have used one **DLL** which works perfectly fine when used in `console` application. But when I use this in a self-hosted **WcfService**, then it gives the error `System.BadImageFormatException`.

What could be the reason, and what is the solution for it?

Comment: Are you attempting to load a 64 bit DLL into a 32-bit process, or vice-versa?

Comment: everything is 64 bit, as the hosting project(code) and WcfServiceLibrary are also part of the same solution.

Comment: They can be part of the same solution but built for different bitness.

Comment: `In IIS 7.x, there is a Advanced Settings property of the application pool called "Enable 32-bit Applications"..set that = true` also explain to us how you are referencing this `DLL` also in the reference node.. set the `CopyLocal=true` had the same issue last week and make sure project is set `AnyCPU`

Comment: Not doing via IIS, self hosted it i.e. installed at URL `"http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":1235/AppService"`.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is an incorrectly set platform target. The bitness of the DLL and the one of the executable must match as you can't load a 64-bit DLL into a 32-bit process (or vice-versa).

Try setting the platform target of the DLL to AnyCPU (Note that the platform target needs to be set per build configuration separately).

Comment: everything is 64 bit, as the hosting project(code) and WcfServiceLibrary are also part of the same solution. I checked bitness of dll using a decompiler, that is also 64 bit.

Comment: "setting the platform target of the DLL to AnyCPU" - that is an external DLL, I am not building it.

Comment: If the DLL is a third-party library than you need to set the platform target of your hosting service to match the one of the DLL.